# Android, TableLayout support RTL and LTR dynamically

Tags: android, tablelayout, right-to-left

I'm developing multi-language app and in RTL languages, the label must be at the right side (opposite of LTR languages). Is there any solution to handle it dynamically? I don't want redesign them again in their own Layout-Folders (like `Layout-En` , `layout-Fa` , ....) because there is a lot of them!

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Android 4.2 or above then you can use the Android native RTL support. by adding `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the application manifest, Android will mirror the default layout to RTL more details see [Native RTL support in Android 4.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+blogspot/hsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29). For older versions the only way is to redesign them for the RTL.